# Permutations and Combinations with letters

Tags: permutations, combinations, education

Using the word **ALOHOMORA**, find how many arrangements are possible if the letter O's were seen as different from each other (distinguishable) **and** they are to be separated.

Comment: The O's are distinguishable but the A's aren't?

Comment: Write down the $6$ non-O's, with a little space between them. They determine $7$ gaps (including the two ends). We **choose** $3$ of these gaps to slip an O into. Then we permute the $6$ non-O, permute the $3$ O, divide by $2$ to deal with the fact that A's are (presumably) identical.

Answer (score 2):

Permute ALHMRA in $\dfrac{6!}{2!}$ ways,

and place the (distinct) $O's$ at the uparrows $\;\;\uparrow A\uparrow L\uparrow H\uparrow M\uparrow R\uparrow A\uparrow \;$in $7\;\cdot6\cdot5\;$ ways

Multiply the two